# Python Sympy Arbitrary Approximation to Arbitrary Sympy Expression?

Tags: python, sympy, approximation, mpmath

I find myself wanting to use approxmations provided as part of the mpmath package, but getting confused on exactly what they are supposed to be doing:

http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/mpmath/calculus/approximation.html

What exactly is the difference between a sympy expression and a sympy.mpmath expression ?

If I want a taylor approximation to a symbolic expression without understanding what mpmath package is doing I can do the following:

```
#Imports
import sympy
import sympy.parsing
import sympy.parsing.sympy_parser
import Library_TaylorApproximation

#Create a sympy expression to approximate
ExampleStringExpression = 'sin(x)'
ExampleSympyExpression = sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr(ExampleStringExpression)


#Create a taylor expantion sympy expression around the point x=0
SympyTaylorApproximation = sympy.series( 
    ExampleSympyExpression,
    sympy.Symbol('x'),
    1, 
    4,
    ).removeO()

#Cast the sympy expressions to python functions which can be evaluated:
VariableNames = [str(var) for var in SympyTaylorApproximation.free_symbols]
PythonFunctionOriginal =  sympy.lambdify(VariableNames, ExampleSympyExpression)
PythonFunctionApproximation = sympy.lambdify(VariableNames, SympyTaylorApproximation)

#Evaluate the approximation and the original at a point:
print PythonFunctionOriginal(2)
print PythonFunctionApproximation(2)

#>>> 0.909297426826
#>>> 0.870987413961
```

However, if I try to do the same thing with mpmath based on the documentation:

```
TaylorCoefficients = sympy.mpmath.taylor(ExampleSympyExpression, 1, 4 )
print 'TaylorCoefficients', TaylorCoefficients

#>>> TypeError: 'sin' object is not callable
```

I can try to cram the python function in there (which is callable):

```
TaylorCoefficients = sympy.mpmath.taylor(PythonFunctionOriginal, 1, 4 )
print 'TaylorCoefficients', TaylorCoefficients

#>>> TaylorCoefficients [mpf('0.8414709848078965'), mpf('0.0'), mpf('0.0'), mpf('0.0'), mpf('-8.3694689805155739e+57')]
```

But the above does not make any sense, because I know that derivatives cannot be taken of a python function.

I can call the mpmath function `sin`:

```
TaylorCoefficients = sympy.mpmath.taylor(sympy.mpmath.sin, 1, 4 )
print 'TaylorCoefficients', TaylorCoefficients
#>>> TaylorCoefficients [mpf('0.8414709848078965'), mpf('0.54030230586813977'), mpf('-0.42073549240394825'), mpf('-0.090050384311356632'), mpf('0.035061291033662352')]
```

But then I cannot do manipulations on it the way I would want too -> like If I want

```
SinTimesCos = sympy.mpmath.sin*sympy.mpmath.cos
TaylorCoefficients = sympy.mpmath.taylor(SinTimesCos, 1, 4 )
print 'TaylorCoefficients', TaylorCoefficients
#>>> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'function'
```

Exactly WHAT is an mpmath function ?

It is not a sympy expression, and it is also not a python function. How do I do manipulations on arbitrary expressions?

It would appear that I cannot take approximations of arbitrary sympy expressions in the documentation. 
http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/mpmath/calculus/approximation.html

How do I take arbitrary approximations ( Pade / Cheby Chev / Fourier ) 
to arbitrary sympy expressions?

EDIT:

So an example of what I am looking for is the following approximation:

```
#Start with a sympy expression of (a, b, x)
expressionString = 'cos(a*x)*sin(b*x)*(x**2)'
expressionSympy = sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr(expressionString)

#Do not want to decide on value of `a or b` in advance.
#Do want approximation with respect to x:

wantedSympyExpression = SympyChebyChev( expressionSympy, sympy.Symbol('x') )
```

Result could either be a list of coefficient expressions that are functions of `a`, and `b`:

```
wantedSympyExpressionCoefficients = [ Coef0Expression(a,b), Coef1Expression(a,b), ... , CoefNExpression(a,b)]
```

OR the result could be the entire sympy expression itself (which is itself a function of `a`, `b`):

```
wantedSympyExpression = Coef0Expression(a,b) + Coef1Expression(a,b) *(x**2) + ... + CoefNExpression(a,b) (x**N)
```

Note that `a` and `b` are not chosen in advance of performing the approximation.

Answer (score 1):

mpmath functions are ordinary Python functions. They simply do their math in arbitrary-precision arithmetic.

> But the above does not make any sense, because I know that derivatives cannot be taken of a python function.

You can't take the derivative *symbolically*, but you can compute an approximation of the derivative by evaluating the function several times and using numerical differentiation techniques. This is what `sympy.mpmath.taylor` does. Quoting the docs:

> The coefficients are computed using high-order numerical differentiation. The function must be possible to evaluate to arbitrary precision.

Comment: So - my `PythonFunctionOriginal` cannot be evaluated to arbitrary precision?

Comment: @DAdams: Correct. That's most likely why the higher-order terms of the taylor series ended up as zero.

Comment: This answer was extremely insightful regarding an explanation of what npmath functions are doing. Perhaps we could migrate this answer, and the question `What exactly is the difference between a sympy expression and a sympy.mpmath expression ?` to another page?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a SymPy expression and want to evaluate it to arbitrary precision, use `evalf`, like

```
sympy.sin(1).evalf(100)
```

You can use `sin(x).evalf(100, subs={x:1})` to replace the `x` with `1` before evaluating. `evalf` uses mpmath under the hood, so this will give you the same result that mpmath would, but without having to use mpmath directly.

Comment: I'm unclear what your issue is. Can you show an example? If it doesn't fit in a comment you can open a new question.

Comment: I am hoping to generate a set of symbolic coefficients for the chebychev/pade/fourier of an arbitrary symbolic expression. I edited the last few lines of the question for clarity.

Comment: It would be better to write that as a new question. This answers your original question ("what is the difference between a sympy expression and an mpmath expression?").